# Finding rate of traffic accidents

Tags: calculus

> $A$ is the annual number of traffic accidents, and it is related to the population of a city $P$ by $$p^{3/2}-500A=2500$$
>   If $p=40,000$ and $p'=500$ per year, approximate the rate of change of the number of accidents measured in accidents per year.

The answer is $300$, but I don't understand how this is the case. It sounds like I'm integrating A and plugging in $p=40,000$, but I get nowhere near 300. I've tried differentiating A and still got nothing out of it. How do I solve this?

Comment: Implicit differentiation: $1.5p^{0.5}p'-500\frac{dA}{dt}=[2500]'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Try writing this expression as:
$$p(t)^{3/2}-500A(t)=2500$$ and now differentiating with respect to time., since you're looking to approximate $\dot{A(t)}=\frac{dA}{dt}(t)$.